# Is it possible to highlight a search pattern when codemirror loads

Tags: codemirror

Is there a way for codemirror to highlight the code matching a pattern (like if I use the search addon) when the page load? So I could load the page with ?search=my_pattern and pass the pattern to codemirror.

Here's a sample code and a jsfiddle. You can use CTRL+F to use the search addon.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/codemirror.css" />
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/search.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/searchcursor.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/match-highlighter.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/python.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="myTextArea">print "hello world"</textarea>
        <script>
        var myTextArea = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
        var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea, {
            'mode': 'python',
            'lineNumbers': true
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ErxMb/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using [overlay.js](http://codemirror.net/addon/mode/overlay.js) by looking at the [CodeMirror: Overlay Parser Demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/mustache.html).

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/codemirror.css" />
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/search.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/searchcursor.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/overlay.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/match-highlighter.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/python.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .cm-highlightSearch {background: yellow;}
    </style>
    <body>
        <textarea id="myTextArea">print "hello world"</textarea>
        <script>
        var keyword = 'hello';

        CodeMirror.defineMode("highlightSearch", function(config, parserConfig) {
          var searchOverlay = {
            token: function(stream, state) {
                if (stream.match(keyword)) {
                    return "highlightSearch";
                }

                while (stream.next() != null && !stream.match(keyword, false)) {}
                return null;
            }
          };
          return CodeMirror.overlayMode(CodeMirror.getMode(config, parserConfig.backdrop || "python"), searchOverlay);
        });

        var myTextArea = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
        var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea, {
            'mode': 'highlightSearch',
            'lineNumbers': true
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HkjY7/