# Code Mirror overlay applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

Can I apply a Code Mirror overlay outside the definition of a mode? 
The code below works but seems redundant and slow. I'm defining a mode for each editor/viewer on a page which could be zero to many. How can this be optimized?

Ideally, I would like to define the mode once and then apply the overlay as needed.

I have not been able to find an answer if I can. I want to define a mode (it highlights a search term [(see this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979135/is-it-possible-to-highlight-a-search-pattern-when-codemirror-loads)) and then I want to apply that mode to many editors/viewers on a page. Each editor/viewer has a different language and is set on the DOM element (e.g `<pre class="sourcecode" language="javascript">code</pr>`).

I think the solution would be something dealing with `return CodeMirror.overlayMode(CodeMirror.getMode(config, mode),searchOverlay, true);` but I've been unable to get it to work.

```
$('.sourcecode').each( function() {
        var value = $(this).text(),
            search = (typeof keyword === 'undefined') ? false : true,
            mode =  $(this).attr('language'),
            pre = $(this).get(0),
            line = ($(this).attr('firstLineNumber') == undefined) ? 1 : parseInt($(this).attr('firstLineNumber'), 10);

        // CodeMirror search highlighing

        // this seems redundent, slow, and messy
        if (search) {
            CodeMirror.defineMode("highlightSearch", function(config, parserConfig) {
              var searchOverlay = {
                token: function(stream, state) {
                    if (stream.match(keyword)) {
                        return "highlightSearch";
                    }

                    while (stream.next() != null && !stream.match(keyword, false)) {}
                    return null;
                }
              };
              return CodeMirror.overlayMode(CodeMirror.getMode(config, mode),searchOverlay, true);
            });
        }

        var viewer = CodeMirror(function(elt) {
            pre.parentNode.replaceChild(elt, pre);
        }, {
            value: value,
            lineNumbers: true,
            firstLineNumber: line,
            matchBrackets: true,
            lineWrapping: true,
            readOnly: true,
            mode: (search) ? 'highlightSearch' : mode,
        });
    });
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: this may be a better fit down at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unlikely to be very costly (unless you are creating hundreds of editors per second), but a more elegant solution would be to define your wrapping mode once, and read the inner mode (`mode` variable in your code) from its `parserConfig` object, say `parserConfig.inner`. You'd then simply pass `{name: "highlightSearch", inner: mode}` as your `mode` option.

Comment: Thanks Marijn. Works perfectly. Did I miss the ability to pass an object as the mode in the docs? Also were can I find more info on the parserConfig object?

Comment: The docs for the mode option mention this: http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_mode . The parserConfig object is pretty much the object passed as the mode.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I defined the mode outside the `.each`. Within the mode definition I replaced

```
return CodeMirror.overlayMode(CodeMirror.getMode(config, mode),searchOverlay, true);
```

with

```
return CodeMirror.overlayMode(CodeMirror.getMode(config, parserConfig.inner),searchOverlay, true);
```

and replaced

```
mode: (search) ? 'highlightSearch' : mode,
```

with

```
mode: (search) ? {name: 'highlightSearch', inner: mode} : mode,
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding the full code with the replacements already in place at the bottom